# In Java, how can I cast a base class to an extended/child class?

Tags: java, class

I declared a new class **ProductWithCustomTags** that extends **B2BProductData**.

```
public class ProductWithCustomTags extends B2BProductData {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public Boolean useMapPriceOtherwiseMEPrice;
        public String category03;
        public String category02;
        public String category01;
    }
```

Now my problem is I want to cast an instance of **B2BProductData** variable to the class **ProductWithCustomTags** but it returns an exception. How could I accomplish casting the base class to the child class, with the extended class attributes initially as **null**.

I tried to do it this way directly casting it, with no build errors but produces an exception:

```
B2BProductData productDataBaseClass = getProduct(); // Product getter, ASSUME IT RETURNS AN INSTANCE ALL THE TIME
ProductWithCustomTags derivedObject = (ProductWithCustomTags) productDataBaseClass;
```

Assume getProduct() returns an instance always. I did not elaborate the getter code much because it's not the focus.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] .

Comment: if the instance you want to cast _is not_ a `ProductWithCustomTags` instance (i.e. you're getting a `ClassCastException`), there's no way you'll be able to cast it. I'd suggest implementing a copy constructor in `ProductWithCustomTags` such as `public ProductWithCustomTags (B2BProductData source)` and create a new instance instead.

Comment: Exception trace maybe?!

Comment: What is the exception?  What does `getProduct()` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless a variable of base class references a proper instance of a subclass to which you wish to cast, you cannot cast a base class to a subclass.

In your situation it appears that the objects that you get are of the base class or one of its subclasses other than `ProductWithCustomTags`. In this case it is better to wrap an object of the base class, rather than inheriting it:

```
public class ProductWithCustomTags {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final B2BProductData productData;
    public Boolean useMapPriceOtherwiseMEPrice;
    public String category03;
    public String category02;
    public String category01;
    public ProductWithCustomTags(B2BProductData d) {
        productData = d;
    }
    public B2BProductData getProductData() {
        return productData;
    }
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
ProductWithCustomTags derivedObject = new ProductWithCustomTags(getProduct());
```

Comment: This might have not answered my question directly but this is a good alternative instead of creating a constructor for each method and attributes of the parent type.

Comment: @JesKeshlyCruz Generally, when you want to name your class "X with Y", it is a strong hint that composition (i.e. a member of type X) is preferable to inheritance (i.e. extending X) in this situation.

Answer (score -1):

You may misinterpret what casting means. Casting doesn't transform objects. An object doesn't mutate. But in Java, you manipulate objects through references, and a reference is typed, which means that through that reference you can only see part of the object (the part defined by the type of the reference). Now if you know that the object behind is of a given kind then you can cast the reference of a type to another type. Of course this only works if the object is compliant.

So given a `Dog` which you can restrictively see as an `Animal`, you can retrieve it :

```
class Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}

Animal a = new Dog(); // `a` is a Dog! viewed as an Animal
Dog d = (Dog)a; // Ok try to retrieve the dog behind the animal...
```

So if your `getProduct()` method doesn't return an instance of `ProductWithCustomTags` then you can't cast it down.

Comment: Maybe that an explanation of his problem, but so far just a guessed wild shot at the problem. And no, i didnt downvote.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ it doesn't mutate from type system point of view.

Comment: Assume getProduct() returns an instance always. I did not elaborate the getter code much because it's not the focus.

Comment: @JesKeshlyCruz Of course it, what `getProduct` returns plays a role during the cast.